react-quill integration with quill-better-table is not working
I have a react js project where i have used react-quill editor like this
I am trying to add a custom plugin of quill-better-plugin but its not working


import { Quill } from "react-quill";
import React, { lazy, Suspense, useState } from "react";

import QuillBetterTable from "quill-better-table";

const ReactQuill = lazy(() => import("react-quill"));

// related to text editor
const modules = {
  toolbar: [
    [{ font: [] }],
    [{ header: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, false] }],
    ["bold", "italic", "underline", "strike"],
    [{ color: [] }, { background: [] }],
    [{ script: "sub" }, { script: "super" }],
    ["blockquote", "code-block"],
    [{ list: "ordered" }, { list: "bullet" }],
    [{ indent: "-1" }, { indent: "+1" }, { align: [] }],
    ["link", "image", "video"],
    ["clean"],
  ],
  betterTable: {},
  clipboard: {
    matchVisual: false,
  },
};

const TextEditor = ({ value = "", onChange, name }) => {
  Quill.register({ "modules/better-table": QuillBetterTable }, true);

  const rules = [
    { required: true, message: `Please enter blog content` },
    {
      min: 512,
      message: "Blog content must be 512 characters long!",
    },
  ];
  return (
  
      <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
        <ReactQuill
          name="blogcontent"
          modules={modules}
          value={value}
          onChange={onChange}
          theme="snow"
          placeholder="Content goes here..."
          required
        />
      </Suspense>
   
  );
};



but its giving me an error like this
moduleClass is not a constructor
TypeError: moduleClass is not a constructor
Can anyone please help me with that??
A big thank you in advance!!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60043804/how-to-use-quill-better-table-inside-react-quill same question
